# place SCNNode fixed in place without ARPlaneAnchor

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm currently trying to put an SCNNode **fixed in place** while use **ARImageTrackingConfiguration** which is no plane detection but it seems like not working properly because the SCNNode is moving while camera moves

below are the code:

```
/// show cylinder line
func showCylinderLine(point a: SCNVector3, point b: SCNVector3, object: VirtualObject) {
    let length = Vector3Helper.distanceBetweenPoints(a: a, b: b)
    let cyclinderLine = GeometryHelper.drawCyclinderBetweenPoints(a: a, b: b, length: length, radius: 0.001, radialSegments: 10)
    cyclinderLine.name = "line"
    cyclinderLine.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cyclinderLine)
    cyclinderLine.look(at: b, up: self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.worldUp, localFront: cyclinderLine.worldUp)
}
```

is it possible to make the cylinderLine SCNNode fixed in place without ARPlaneAnchor ?

(**Note**: I had tried ARAnchor on nodeForAnchor delegate methods and it is still moving as camera moves)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your nodeForAnchors method?
That is where nodes are "fixed" to the image so i am guessing an error is there somewhere. Here is one example application of that delegate:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

    let node = SCNNode()

    if let _ = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
      if let objectScene = SCNScene(named: "ARassets.scnassets/object.scn") {

        //creates a new node that is connected to the image. This is what makes your object "fixed"
        let objectNode = objectScene.rootNode.childNodes.first!

        objectNode.position = SCNVector3Zero
        objectNode.position.y = 0.15

        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
      }
    }
```

Let me know if this helps ;)

Comment: Hi, I would like to render a line between two SCNNode objects

Comment: I did not use nodeFor Anchor methods for rendering the line but used to render other objects on top of the ARImageAnchor